# TKINTER: Close All Open Child Windows But Leave Parent Window Open

Tags: python, tkinter

First, hello and thanks for assisting me with my Python/tkinter question!

I would like to be able to close all open child windows and leave the root window open when closing them.

My sample code is below.  After one opens windows 1 & 2, I would like the third button to close windows 1 & 2 only.

I appreciate any insights!

---

```
import tkinter as tk
    
root = tk.Tk()

def open():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top.title('WINDOW 1')
    top.geometry("300x200+550+150")
    top.mainloop()

def open2():
    top2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top2.title('WINDOW 2')
    top2.geometry("300x200+550+400")
    top2.mainloop()

#def close():
    #

root.geometry('300x200')

btn_1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Open Window 1", background="#949BA4", command = open)
btn_1.place(x=21, y=20)

btn_2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Open Window 2", background="#949BA4", command = open2)
btn_2.place(x=184, y=20)

btn_3 = tk.Button(root, text = "Close Win 1 & 2", background="#9ABDE9", )
btn_3.place(x=75, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `mainloop` for every `Toplevel`. It's designed to be called exactly once for the life of the root window.

Answer (score 0):

**I found my answer:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def open():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top.title('WINDOW 1')
    top.geometry("300x200+550+150")
    top.mainloop()

def open2():
    top2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top2.title('WINDOW 2')
    top2.geometry("300x200+550+400")
    top2.mainloop()

def close():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(widget, tk.Toplevel):
            widget.destroy()

root.geometry('300x200')

btn_1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Open Window 1", background="#949BA4", command = open)
btn_1.place(x=21, y=20)

btn_2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Open Window 2", background="#949BA4", command = open2)
btn_2.place(x=184, y=20)

btn_3 = tk.Button(root, text = "Close Win 1 & 2", background="#9ABDE9", command = close)
btn_3.place(x=75, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: also remove `top.mainloop()` and `top2.mainloop()` as @BryanOakley suggested and btw since function have their own scopes, you don't need to use different variable names such as `top` and `top2`